# Center a plot relatively to the middle of a vertical segment

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, tkz-tab

**NEW POST**

Thanks to the code of Black Mild I have almost what I need.

Here is what it remains to do.
**How to center the plot vertically relatively to the middle of the segment [T21 T22] where T21 and T22 are two nodes ?**
I would like the plot to be inside the frame indicated (no need to draw the frame).
More precisely I would like the good height for the plot and for the width the ratio of the inital plot should be kept.

[image]

Here is the updated code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\newcommand\signline[3]{
    \draw[blue]
        (#1.east) +(0:.5) pic[right]{%
            code = {
                \draw[->] (0,0)--+(0:2);
                \draw[blue] (0,.5)node[right=2mm]{$+$}
                            --
                            (2,-.5) node[left=2mm]{$-$};
                \path (1,0) node[above,blue]{#3};
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[
        espcl = 1.5,
%       help % This shows TikZ names of nodes given by tkz-tab.
    ]{
        $x$                         /1,
        Signe de\\ $-x+3$           /1.5,
        Signe de\\ $f(x)$           /1.5,
        Signe de\\ $x^2 + 3x - 4$   /1.5,
        Signe du\\ produit          /1.5
    }{%
         $-\infty$,    $-4$,    $1$,    $3$,   $+\infty$
    }

    \tkzTabLine { , + , t  , + , t , + , z , - }
    \tkzTabLine { , - , z  , + , z , + , z , - }
    \tkzTabLine { , + , z  , - , z , + , t , + }

    \tkzTabLine { , - , z  , - , z , + , z , + }
    
    \signline{T21}{T22}{$3$}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**INITIAL POST**

In the following code I would like to decorate my table as in the picture below.

[image]

Here are my questions for the first plot (the one with the line).

1. How to use 3 nodes to definie a specific cartesian coordinate system ? In my code I will use allways nodes named T21, T22, ... `\tkzTabInit` has an option to see the name of the nodes build.
2. How to use a TikZ plot in another cartesian coordinate system ?

In my case, I would like to build several standard plots (for lines, parabols). Then I will like to put one of them in a specific cartesian coordinate system.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[
        espcl=1.5,
        %help  % ---> This shows TikZ names given by tkz-tab to nodes.
    ]{
        $x$                         /1,
        Signe de\\ $-x+3$           /1.5,
        Signe de\\ $f(x)$           /1.5,
        Signe de\\ $x^2 + 3x - 4$   /1.5,
        Signe du\\ produit          /1.5
    }{%
         $-\infty$,    $-4$,    $1$,    $3$,   $+\infty$
    }

    \tkzTabLine { , + , t  , + , t , + , z , - }
    \tkzTabLine { , - , z  , + , z , + , z , - }
    \tkzTabLine { , + , z  , - , z , + , t , + }

    \tkzTabLine { , - , z  , - , z , + , z , + }
    
    \draw[blue]
        (T21) node[right=2mm]{UP};
    
    \draw[blue]
        (T22) node[right=2mm]{DOWN};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you prefer tikztab to the matrix of nodes?

Comment: The interface programming is very easy to use : the code above is meaningfull. tkz-tab also manages different cases of use like writing the table of sign of a derivative and below the variations associated. I also need a solution that could be used whatever are the numbers of lines and columns. For the moment tkz-tab is the easiest way to do all that kind of things even if the interface programming could be simplified a little (but I do not know if it would be easy to implement concretly without breaking anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thanks to Black Mild's solution** and with a very little search on the web, I can finish the job.
Here is a code to do what I need as it is shown in the following screenshot (the API is not user friendly but the hardest, from my point of view, has been done).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Sources
%   + https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549546/6880
%   + https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fr.comp.text.tex/X6aIq-SZDFA

\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\signline[3]{
    \coordinate (M) at ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$); 
    \path
        (M.east) +(.75,0) pic[right]{%
            code = {
                \draw[->] (0,0)--+(0:2);
                \draw[blue] (0,.5)node[right=2mm]{$+$}
                            --
                            (2,-.5) node[left=2mm]{$-$};
                % Root
                \path (1,0) node[above,blue]{#3};
        }
    };
}


\newcommand\signparabola[4]{
    \coordinate (M) at ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$); 
    \path
        (M.east) +(.75,0) pic[right]{%
            code = {
                \draw[->] (0,0)--+(0:2.5);
                \draw[blue] (0.25,-.6) parabola bend (1.25,.6) (2.25,-.6);
                \path (1.25,0) node[above,blue]{$+$};
                \path (.275,-.3) node[left,blue]{$-$};
                \path (2.25,-.3) node[right,blue]{$-$};
                % Roots
                \path (.25,0) node[above,blue]{#3};
                \path (2.125,0) node[above,blue]{#4};
        }
    };
}


\newcommand\comment[3]{
    \coordinate (M) at ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$); 
    \path
        (M.east) +(.75,0) node[right,blue]{#3}
    ;
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[
        espcl = 1.5,
%       help % This shows TikZ names of nodes given by tkz-tab.
    ]{
        $x$                         /1,
        Signe de\\ $-x+3$           /1.5,
        Signe de\\ $f(x)$           /1.5,
        Signe de\\ $x^2 + 3x - 4$   /1.5,
        Signe du\\ produit          /1.5
    }{%
         $-\infty$,    $-4$,    $1$,    $3$,   $+\infty$
    }

    \tkzTabLine { , + , t  , + , t , + , z , - }
    \tkzTabLine { , - , z  , + , z , + , z , - }
    \tkzTabLine { , - , z  , + , z , - , t , - }

    \tkzTabLine { , + , z  , + , z , - , z , - }
    
    \signline{T21}{T22}{$3$}
    \comment{T22}{T23}{Voir Q.1-a)}
    \signparabola{T23}{T24}{$-4$}{$1$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thank you for editing my most recent answer and I thank you from the heart.

Answer (score 3):

I think `matrix` is more appropriate for this case (drawing something over a table).I did't draw dashed lines because it is not necessary!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,draw,inner sep=0,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={minimum height=10mm,minimum width=8mm,anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes={minimum height=6mm}},
column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=2cm,text width=2.1cm,align=center}},
]{
$x$&$-\infty$&&$-4$&&$1$&&$3$&&$+\infty$\\
{Sign de\\$-x+3$}&&$+$&&$+$&&$+$&$0$&$-$&\\
{Sign de\\$f(x)$}&&$-$&$0$&$+$&$0$&$-$&&$-$&\\
{Sign de\\$x^2-3x+4$}&&$+$&$0$&$-$&$0$&$+$&&$+$&\\
{Sign de\\produit}&&$-$&$0$&$-$&$0$&$-$&$0$&$+$&\\
};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
\draw 
(m-\i-1.south west)--(m-\i-10.south east);
\draw 
(m-1-1.north east)--(m-5-1.south east);
\path 
(m-4-10.east) +(0:.5) node[right,draw,blue]{Another plot}
(m-3-10.east) +(0:.5) node[right,blue]{Cf. q1}
(m-2-10.east) +(0:.5) pic[right]{code={
\draw[->] (0,0)--+(0:2);
\draw[blue] (0,-.5)node[right=2mm]{$-$}--
(2,.5) node[left=2mm]{$+$};
\path (1,0) node[above,blue]{$3$};
}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this proposition that should be a very good starting point for me to do the same thing with tkz-tab that I use a lot for my lessons.

Comment: @projetmbc You are welcome!

Comment: I have juste updated my question.

Comment: @projetmbc ... and you get stuck with the right hand side of the new picture?

Comment: I have updated my question with a small problem remaining to solve.

Comment: @projetmbc In my old code, `\path (m-2-10.east) +(0:.5) pic[right]{code={
\draw[->] (0,0)--+(0:2);
\draw[blue] (0,-.5)node[right=2mm]{$-$}--
(2,.5) node[left=2mm]{$+$};` give pic horizontally relative to the middle of the segment [T21 T22].

Comment: I have post the answer thanks to your code. :-)